# Cycle through hex numbers in Byte array

Tags: java, hex, arrays, brute-force

Hey guys I wanted to know if i could get a little help: Im trying to count up in hex inside of a byte array. What im doing is i have the plain text in the form of 8 hex numbers and the cipher text in the same form as well as the first 4 numbers of the key. And im trying to use the DES to crack the key via brute force.

my key looks like this:

```
[A3 BB 12 44 __ __ __ __]
```

and i want it to start like this i suppose:

```
[A3 BB 12 44 00 00 00 00]
```

then

```
[A3 BB 12 44 00 00 00 01]
```

and so on. I just dont really know how to count in hex. inside of a byte array at that!

any help is much appreciated!

**EDITED AFTER MUCH HELP**

here is find key ( i changed some of the names of things around to better suit my program)

```
public static void findKey(){

    byte [] keyBytes = null;
    byte [] pt;
    byte [] ct;

    codeBreaker KEY = new codeBreaker(new byte[]{(byte)0x01, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x67, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00}, 2 );

    String plaintext = "Plaintxt";
    ct = new byte [] {(byte)0x4A, (byte)0xC4, (byte)0x55, (byte)0x3D, (byte)0xB3, (byte)0x37, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0xB3};

    //convert the plain text "Plaintxt" into a hex byte array
    String ptHex = asciiToHex(plaintext);
    pt = getBytes(ptHex);

    //keyBytes = KEY.inc()

    //my attempt
    /*while(!isKey(pt,keyBytes,ct)){
        KEY.inc(); // something like increase the key by 1 and send t back in.
    }
    */


    //this is your original while loop
    /*while (KEY.inc()) {
        byte[] bytes = KEY.getBytes();
        for (byte b: bytes) {
            System.out.printf("%02X ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    */


    //Final outputs for the findKey method
    System.out.println("        Plain Text In Hex Is:");        
    printByteArray(pt);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("         The Cipher Text Is:");
    printByteArray(ct);
    System.out.println();

}
```

and here is the stuff you came up with

```
    public codeBreaker(byte[] keyAr, int startIndex) {
    this.key = keyAr;
    this.startIndex = startIndex;
}

   public boolean inc() {
   int i;
   for (i = key.length-1; i >= startIndex; i--) {
       key[i]++;
       if (key[i] != 0)
           break;
   }
        // we return false when all bytes are 0 again
   return (i >= startIndex || key[startIndex] != 0);
}

public byte[] getBytes() {
    return key;
}
```

which I all put into one class and called it codeBreaker with the rest of the methods i have (but those other ones dont have anything to do with this specific part)

Comment: *"Hey was wondering if i could get a little intellectual help"*  - Not round here mate.  We're all just "dumb programmers" ... just like you :-) :-)

Comment: @StephenC: speak for yourself. I consider myself an intellectual heavy weight, right up there with Rush Limbaugh and Donald Trump.

Comment: Seriously though, a byte doesn't know or care if it's hex or not since that's just the String representation of the byte. Can you give more background on just what you're trying to do? Where the byte array is coming from, why you can't simply iterate through it with a for loop, etc...

Comment: The secret text is: `PLAINTXT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this one?

```
public class ByteIncrement
{
    private final byte[] bytes;
    private final int startIndex;
    public ByteIncrement(byte[] bytes, int startIndex) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
    }
    public boolean inc() {
        int i;
        for (i = bytes.length-1; i >= startIndex; i--) {
            bytes[i]++;
            if (bytes[i] != 0)
                break;
        }
        // we return false when all bytes are 0 again
        return (i >= startIndex || bytes[startIndex] != 0);
    }
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ByteIncrement bi = new ByteIncrement(new byte[]{(byte)0xa4, 0x56, 0x17, (byte)0x9f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 2 ); // first two bytes are constant -> 2
        while (bi.inc()) {
            byte[] bytes = bi.getBytes();
            for (byte b: bytes) {
                System.out.printf("%02X ", b);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so will this after one call return .... 00 00 00 01 ?  like i would need to be able to increment it once send the new incremented byte array through the encryption des and check to see if that cipher text was equal to my given ciphertext, if it wasnt i need to increment again. Or would since i would be returning it and it would now be 00 00 00 01 i wouls just send that back through and the next would be 00 00 00 02 ? What happens when i get up into the a - f?

Comment: after first inc() the result of getBytes() is actually .... 01 00 00 00. I thought it was brute-force and the order didn't matter anyway? If you want it exactly .... 00 00 00 01 then the for loop would have to be iterated backwards `i = bytes.length-1; i >= startIndex; i--` and the return value is `i >= startIndex || bytes[startIndex] != 0`. The inc returns false, when all values have flipped to .... 00 00 00 00 again.

Comment: OK - I see from your edited definition that the backwards loop is what you actually want. I will change the code

Comment: no you dont need to do that It really doesnt matter! I just wanted to know that after one say the 10th iteration will what i get back be 0a 00 00 00 or would it be something else? And thanks for your help btw because i do need it in that form in order to run through the DES

Comment: Well - you could just execute the program and look at the output if it does what you want. Play around with it and debug it. I hope that helped :)

Comment: Been playing around with this for a bit, THIS THING IS AWESOME hahah! thanks for the help man! haven't quite adjusted it all the way to my code yet but im working on it! works like a charm!

Comment: I have incorporated it into my program, but I am having trouble getting an instance of the key out. That on method inc() is boolean, and i tried to alter it to it was byte[] and would return a byte array to me which would be he key i use to check the cipher. It wasnt really working though, any tips for that?

Comment: Well that really depends on your control flow. My implementation works fine when you call it - as in the `main` - `while(bi.inc()) checkResult(bi.getBytes())`. You could also add a method `byte[] next { if (inc()) return bytes else return null;}` and then check later if the result of `next()` is `null`... but that isn't quite as nice. OK - I hope that helped. Otherwise we should really move the discussion to a chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24261/discussion-between-erp-and-michael-s)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void tryCipher (
    byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4,
    byte b5, byte b6, byte b7, byte b8)
{
    // Try the variant, convert to HEX if necessary
}

public static void bruteForce (byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4)
{
    for (int b5 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b5 <= Byte.MAX_VALUE, b5++)
        for (int b6 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b6 <= Byte.MAX_VALUE, b6++)
            for (int b7 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b7 <= Byte.MAX_VALUE, b7++)
                for (int b8 = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b8 <= Byte.MAX_VALUE, b8++)
                    tryCipher (b1, b2, b3, b4, (byte)b5, (byte)b6, (byte)b7, (byte)b8);
}
```